# How to get this value via xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml document like so:

```
<add-server-response>
  <server id="4029" name="" notes="" state="Restoring Harddrive Image">
    <login name="iDRAC" username="dracadmin" password="Ah73849SJu57S1l"/>
    <ip name="system" address="199.16.205.97"/>
  </server>
</add-server-response>
```

From this, I want to get the value of id (4029), via Xpath. What would the corresponding xpath be and is there not a tool that would let me hover over an attribute and see the xpath query?

Thanks

Comment: oXygen XML editor (http://www.oxygenxml.com/) has an xpath builder that will update the xpath on caret move. Very handy sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/add-server-response/server/@id`

Don't know of any tool

Comment: Perfect! I actually did the same but without the / after server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> *is there not a tool that would let me hover over an attribute and see the xpath query?*

You may want have a look at:

- [Firebug Firefox extension](http://getfirebug.com/)
- [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359)

These browser extensions, among many other useful functionalities, provide a "get XPath" like command on the selected node.

The XPath is returned as an exact (position dependent) and [**absolute location path**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-AbsoluteLocationPath).

Used directly on this web page I'm receiving:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/pre/code/span[5]
```

But if you use it against an pure XML like your, you would receive:

```
/add-server-response/server/@id
```

Comment: Another tool is liquid-xml, actually.